# deprecated fields in graphql-js not displayed

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, deprecated, apollo-server, graphql-js

I recently moved graphql-js version to 15.5 and when i use deprecated fields on queries they don't appear in graphql playground and in the graphql schema.

```
new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'InputField',
  fields: {
    id: {
      deprecationReason: 'Not used anymore',
      description: 'id',
      type: GraphQLID,
    },
...
  },
});
```

I use apollo-server to generate the schema, and when i use on client side apollo:gen:schema the schema is regenerated without deprecated fields.

Before it worked correctly.